# Subscribe method without Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am new to Angular 5 and I have done following methods for login a user. Following are my functions. But I am confused with observable because all articles are saying subscribe method with observable with Rx.

Is there any wrong in my method implementation. I haven't used Rxjs library.

My `login.ts`

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { RestProvider } from '../../providers/rest/rest';
login(data) {
    this.restProvider.loginToken(this.registerCredentials).subscribe((data : any)=>{
      localStorage.setItem('userToken',data.access_token);

    },
    (err : HttpErrorResponse)=>{
      this.isLoginError = true;
    });
  }
```

My `Rest.ts`

```typescript
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

  apiUrl='http://localhost:26264'
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
  }

loginToken(data){
  var details = this.jsonToURLEncoded({ grant_type:'password', username:data.email, password:data.password,});
  var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-urlencoded','No-Auth':'True' });
  const options = {
    headers: reqHeader



  }
  console.log(details);
  return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/token', details, options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) if you look  into this class you could see it returns an `Observable<any>` type this mean this feature is builtin feature with `HttpClient`

```typescript
class HttpClient {
  request(first: string | HttpRequest<any>, url?: string, options: {...}): Observable<any>
  delete(url: string, options: {...}): Observable<any>
  get(url: string, options: {...}): Observable<any>
  head(url: string, options: {...}): Observable<any>
  jsonp<T>(url: string, callbackParam: string): Observable<T>
  options(url: string, options: {...}): Observable<any>
  patch(url: string, body: any | null, options: {...}): Observable<any>
  post(url: string, body: any | null, options: {...}): Observable<any>
  put(url: string, body: any | null, options: {...}): Observable<any>
}
```

[From Angular DOC](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular)

> Angular makes use of observables as an interface to handle a variety
>   of common asynchronous operations.
>
> For example:
>
> - The EventEmitter class extends Observable.
> - The HTTP module uses observables to handle AJAX requests and    responses.
> - The Router and Forms modules use observables to listen for and    respond to user-input events.

Therefor in these cases you no need to use `Rxjs` directly using the their library

You have used `this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/token', details, options);` this is also return Observable

[From Angular DOC](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)

> Constructs an Observable which, when subscribed, will cause the
>   configured POST request to be executed on the server. See the
>   individual overloads for details of post()'s return type based on the
>   provided options.
>
> **Eg.**
>   Construct a POST request which interprets the body as an ArrayBuffer and returns it.
>
> ```typescript
> post(url: string, body: any | null, options: {
>     headers?: HttpHeaders | {
>         [header: string]: string | string[];
>     };
>     observe?: 'body';
>     params?: HttpParams | {
>         [param: string]: string | string[];
>     };
>     reportProgress?: boolean;
>     responseType: 'arraybuffer';
>     withCredentials?: boolean;
> }): Observable<ArrayBuffer>
> ```
>
> See more [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)

Also refer these links

- [Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables)
- [The RxJS library](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#the-rxjs-library)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I am able to get token from server but I can see response two times i .e 200 Ok. It shows two times. Does it mean that the code executes 2 times ? Actually I clicked on button only one time.

Comment: make sure to unsubscribe to the `this.restProvider.loginToken` subscription when the component destroy. e.g. first declare a `subscription: ISubscription;` variable and assign `subscription = this.restProvider.loginToken(this.registerCredentials).subscribe...` and implements `OnDestroy` on your component and  inside `ngOnDestroy()` use like this `this.subscription.unsubscribe();`

Answer (score 1):

Observable is a pattern and rxjs a library that implement the observable pattern.

**rxjs** is one of building base of angular core , many of angular api return observable,
why to subscribe ? observable is lazy that is one diffrent between `Promise`,for example `HttpClient` request will be made when you use subscribe.

you can read more about this in [angular doc - observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables)